# When current menu item is selected, others fade

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Example:

I am in the "Contact" page. I want the "Contact" menu item to be at 100% opacity and the rest at 30% opacity.
I am in the "About" page. I want the "About" menu item to be at 100% opacity and the rest at 30% opacity.

My menu is this: 
[image: http://i.imgur.com/KUlBovk.jpg]

HTML:

```
<ul class="menu">
<li class="menu-item menu-item-1"><a href="some_link">Home</a></li> 
<li class="menu-item menu-item-2 current-menu-item"><a href="some_link">Contact</a></li> 
<li class="menu-item menu-item-3"><a href="some_link">About</a></li>
</ul>
```

CSS:

```
.menu .menu-item-1 {background: url('images/image1.jpg');}
.menu .menu-item-1 a {background: url('images/transparent-black-border-1.png') no-repeat;  background-position: bottom;}
.menu .menu-item-2 {background: url('images/image2.jpg');}
.menu .menu-item-2 a {background: url('images/transparent-black-border-2.png') no-repeat;  background-position: bottom;}
.menu .menu-item-3 {background: url('images/image3.jpg');}
.menu .menu-item-3 a {background: url('images/transparent-black-border-3.png') no-repeat;  background-position: bottom;}
```

**What I want:**
When the .current-menu-item class appears, that menu item should be at 100 opacity and the others at 30%. Also the .menu .menu-item-1 background image should fade too, not only the a-tag.

Can you help me?

Comment: have you looked up anything in this space? there are many jquery plugins which already exist for this feature

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the not() function..

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/a3Qqp/)

JS:

```
$(".menu-item").on('mouseenter', function(){
  $(".menu-item").find('a').not($(this).find('a')).css('opacity','0.3')
}).on('mouseleave', function(){
  $(".menu-item").find('a').css('opacity','1');
});
```

HTML:

```
<ul class="menu">
  <li class="menu-item"><a href="some_link">Some text</a></li> 
  <li class="menu-item"><a href="some_link">Some text</a></li> 
  <li class="menu-item"><a href="some_link">Some text</a></li>
</ul>
```

Note: Having an anchor-tag inside an ul is a bad practice. There should be only li-tags inside an ul. Therefor I put the a-tag inside each list.

E: After your update you say you want to have the current page on opacity 1 all the time and the rest on 0.3. On hover you want the hovered li element to go on 1 as well.

[Updated Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/a3Qqp/1/)

In your HTML markup you set the class active at each page for the desired menu-item. Give that class an opacity of 1 and the rest of the menu items an opacity of 0.3. On hover do not touch the active class but the others.

HTML:

```
<ul class="menu">
  <li class="menu-item active"><a href="some_link">Home</a></li> 
  <li class="menu-item"><a href="some_link">Page1</a></li> 
  <li class="menu-item"><a href="some_link">Page2</a></li>
</ul>
```

CSS:

```
.menu-item {
  opacity: 0.3;
}
.active {
  opacity: 1;
}
```

JS:

```
$(".menu-item").on('mouseenter', function(){
  $(this).not('.active').css('opacity','1')
}).on('mouseleave', function(){
  $(this).not('.active').css('opacity','0.3');
});
```

Comment: yeah sorry, the a tag was inside the li tag. What your code does: When i hover over an item, that item maintains it's opacity and the others go to 0.3 opacity. What I want is when i enter on a menu item that has a class of .current-menu-item, that current menu item should stay at 100% opacity, and the rest at 30% opacity, not just on hover. I will edit my post for a better understanding.

Comment: @Pufarina Then just add this CSS `a.current-menu-item { opacity: 1; }` &  `.menu a { opacity: .3 }`. Set the current-menu-item class on the active link. This is a good answer. I would only add that instead of chaining jquery methods, it would be more efficient to pass an object, eg. `.on({mouseenter: function() {...}, mouseleave: function() {...})`

Comment: I did this at frist (with CSS). The problem is that on the HOME page, the Home menu item is at 100% opacity and others are at 30%. I want when I am on my HOME page, all my menu items to be at 100% opacity. For this i think i need jQuery.

Comment: I edited the post to have your 'home' / current page you are on remaining opacity 1.

Answer (score 0):

To change the opacity you can do something like this:

```
$(".menu-item").hover(function(){
    $(".menu-item").each(function(){
         $(this).css("opacity", 0.8);
    })
    $(this).css("opacity", 1);
});
```

For easier selector, it would be better to change your HTML structure into this:

```
<ul class="menu">
    <li class="menu-item menu-item-1">...</li> <a href="some_link">Some text</a>
    <li class="menu-item menu-item-2">...</li> <a href="some_link">Some text</a>
    <li class="menu-item menu-item-3">...</li> <a href="some_link">Some text</a>
</ul>
```

For changing the image into B&W/grayscale you need to use HTML5 Canvas, and use this [jQuery.BlackAndWhite](http://gianlucaguarini.github.io/jQuery.BlackAndWhite/)..